# SalesForce Mail Merge attachment

Tags: email

I can have an activity logged during the mail merge creation process, but Salesforce won't automatically attach file to the record.

How do I do this using custom development(apex/VisualForce))?

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you step out the process?

Comment: 1.from case select mail merge 2. Select the mail merge template 3. choose log an activity 4.click generate will create a new task. I want now the template I chose to be attached to the newly created task. SF normally sends the file via email

Comment: I suggest you save time and go for Conga Composer : it will do this for you very easily, and much more !  A lot of cheap powerful added value; keep your Dev power for more important things !  Good luck.